# a is undefined - google maps markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Could you please help me out with the error I get.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
          html { height: 100% }
          body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
          #map_canvas { height: 100% }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="Google.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          var map;
          function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
              zoom:13,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.697, 23.322),
              mapTypeControl: false,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                mapOptions);
          }
        </script>

      </head>
      <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:800px; 600px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {            
            $.getJSON( 'data.json', function(data) { 
                $.each( data.pin, function(i, m) {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(m.latitude, m.longitude), 'bounds':true } );
                });
            });
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>

and here is the JSON file:
     {
    "pins": {
        "pin": {
            "name": "Sofia Bike Rental",
            "latitude": "42.692821",
            "longitude": "23.328738",            
            "contact": "www.sofiabikerental.com",
            "type": "rent"
        },   
        "pin": {
            "name": "Sofia Rent Center",
            "latitude": "42.6674952",
            "longitude": "23.2857399",            
            "contact": "www.sofiarentcenter.com",
            "type": "rent"
        },  
        "pin": {
            "name": "Drag Zone",
            "latitude": "42.6700007",
            "longitude": "23.2928839",            
            "contact": "www.velomania-bg.com",
            "type": "service"
        },   
        "pin": {
            "name": "True Riders",
            "latitude": "42.682068",
            "longitude": "23.322313",            
            "contact": "www.trueriders.bg",
            "type": "service"
        },   
        "pin": {
            "name": "NDK",
            "latitude": "42.685882",
            "longitude": "23.318138",                        
            "type": "parking"
        },   
        "pin": {
            "name": "Sofia municipality",
            "latitude": "42.696701",
            "longitude": "23.332965",            
            "type": "parking"
        }
    }
}
```

I am receiving a is undefined all the time. I am trying to  add these markers on the map and make a infoBox for them, could you please advie me how to proceed.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is in Google.js?  Where does `$('#map_canvas').gmap` come from?  Are you including that library?

Comment: in Google.js is this code http://gmap.nurtext.de/js/jquery.gmap-1.1.0-min.js
I hade reworked the function to this look: $(document).ready(function() {
   $.getJSON("data.json", function(json1) {
     $.each(json1.pins, function(key, data) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude);        
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: latLng
     });
    marker.setMap(map);
     });
   });
    });

But now it shows me only the last item from JSON file...

Comment: That is your problem.  [That code](http://gmap.nurtext.de/js/jquery.gmap-1.1.0-min.js) is not compatible with the Google Maps Javascript API v3, it was written against v2.  I get two errors with your code. 1. `Uncaught ReferenceError: G_NORMAL_MAP is not defined`, 2. `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Comment: So could you please advise me how to proceed. If it was clear for me I wouldn't ask here:) Thank you!

Comment: Either you need a version of the gmap library that is compatible with the Google Maps Javascript API v3, or you need to only use native API methods.

Answer (score 1):

1. you've obviously mixed up the libraries, the method `addMarker` is available in [jquery.ui.map](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) ....so use this library instead of the library from http://gmap.nurtext.de
2. the JSON doesn't have a `pin`-property, the name of the property is `pins`.
   But although your JSON is valid, it will not create the expected result. Property-names have to be unique, the `pins`-property of the returned JSON will only contain a single `pin`-property. You may validate the JSON at http://jsonlint.com/ and you will see that the result is:

   ```
   {
   "pins": {
       "pin": {
           "name": "Sofia municipality",
           "latitude": "42.696701",
           "longitude": "23.332965",
           "type": "parking"
       }
   }
   }
   ```

The content of your JSON-file should be:

```
{
    "pins": [
      {
            "name": "Sofia Bike Rental",
            "latitude": "42.692821",
            "longitude": "23.328738",            
            "contact": "www.sofiabikerental.com",
            "type": "rent"
        },   
         {
            "name": "Sofia Rent Center",
            "latitude": "42.6674952",
            "longitude": "23.2857399",            
            "contact": "www.sofiarentcenter.com",
            "type": "rent"
        },  
         {
            "name": "Drag Zone",
            "latitude": "42.6700007",
            "longitude": "23.2928839",            
            "contact": "www.velomania-bg.com",
            "type": "service"
        },   
         {
            "name": "True Riders",
            "latitude": "42.682068",
            "longitude": "23.322313",            
            "contact": "www.trueriders.bg",
            "type": "service"
        },   
        {
            "name": "NDK",
            "latitude": "42.685882",
            "longitude": "23.318138",                        
            "type": "parking"
        },   
        {
            "name": "Sofia municipality",
            "latitude": "42.696701",
            "longitude": "23.332965",            
            "type": "parking"
        }
]    
}
```

...then you be able to draw the markers by looping over `data.pins`.

**Additionally:**
When you use the `jquery.ui.map` you may simply create the map via :

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap();
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/t5cfgjdu/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/t5cfgjdu/)